# How to convert weekdays to binary-string type? google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The [`NETWORKDAYS.INTL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385) functions accepts 4 arguments. In which the 3rd argument are the weekdays and in which it is binary-string type e.g. `1000000` (for monday only).

My problem is my sheet accepts array-string in a single cell. Which like for example `Monday, Tuesday`.

My question is do we have available predefined function that converts `Monday, Tuesday` to binary-string type e.g. `1100000`? If there are none, do you know how to do it? I'm thinking of regex but I don't know how to do it as well in the sheet.

Comment: You can use `IFS()` or a lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is such predefined function.

You can try:

`=ArrayFormula(JOIN("",N(COUNTIF(MATCH(SPLIT("Monday, Tuesday",", ",0),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0),SEQUENCE(7))>0)))`

1. Split the input into an array of weekdays
2. `MATCH` and get the 1-based index of the weekdays
3. Convert the presence of the index into binary string

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach you can try:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B1,B10,LAMBDA(z,IFNA(IFS(LEN(C1)>10,IF(z>6,1,z+1),LEN(C1)>0,--("1"&z)),REPT(0,7)))(INDEX(XMATCH(LEFT(C1,3),TEXT(SEQUENCE(7),"DDD")))))
```

- 

[image]